# Limit of a sequence of functions on interval

Tags: analysis

If fn is a sequence riemann integrable in [a,b] that converges to a riemann integrable function f in [a.b] , why this equation may not hold ? ( The sequence is not uniformly convergent)

$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx = \lim_{n \to +\infty}\int_{a}^{b}f_n(x)dx $$

Im looking for an intuitive explanation

Comment: In what sense does $f_n \to f$? Pointwise?

Comment: Yes . My doubt is , even if pointwise , for n -> +∞ , fn -> f . So why may happens that the equality doesnt hold ?

Answer (score 2):

There's any number of standard counterexamples, which you should make sure you are familiar with.

Consider $f_n: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ which is $0$ on $[\frac{1}{n}, 1]$ and is a linear interpolation from $0$ to $n$ on $[0, \frac{1}{2n}]$, and is a linear interpolation from $n$ to $0$ on $[\frac{1}{2n}, \frac{1}{n}]$.
Then the area under the curve is the area of a triangle with base $\frac{1}{n}$ and height $n$, so is $\frac{1}{2}$. But the functions converge pointwise to the zero function which has integral $0$.

The point is that pointwise convergence doesn't really constrain the functions very much, and that pathologies over a very small interval can do very bad things to the integral. Pointwise convergence allows all kinds of disgusting things to happen, as long as they happen over smaller and smaller regions.

Comment: What it means that in the uniform convergence every point has the same VELOCITY of convergence ? Thanks

Comment: I think you want $[\frac{1}{2n}, \frac{1}{n}]$ for your third interval.